# c++ send data to multiple UDP sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, broadcast

I got a c++ non-blocking server socket, with all the clients stored in a std::map structure.

I can call the send() method for each clientObject to send something to the connected client and that works pretty good already.

But for sending a message to all (broadcast?) i wanna know:
there is something better than do a for/loop with all the clients and call to ClientObject->send("foo") each iteration?

Or should i just try having a peek on multicast sockets?

Thanks in advance.
Rag.

Comment: Have you considered using the ASIO library? http://asio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How exactly does the ASIO library help the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multicast is only an option if you're communicating over a LAN.  It won't work over the Internet.

What you may want to do here is to demultiplex the sockets using asynchronous I/O.  This allows you to send data to multiple sockets at the same time, and use asynchronous event handlers to deal with each transmission.

I would recommend looking into Boost ASIO for a portable way to do this.  You can also use OS specific system calls, (such as poll/select on UNIX or epoll on Linux) to do this, but it is a lot more complicated.

Comment: Multicast works over the Internet, given some restrictions and some proper router configuration that is usually forgotten by most network admins. Just one example, you can listen to high-quality radio or watch high-quality TV from BBC over multicast: http://www.bbc.co.uk/multicast/

Answer (score 1):

Multicast would be much preferable... as long as you are talking about local nodes i.e. within the "broadcast/multicast" domain on the LAN.

Of course there are multicast distribution protocols for wider dispersion of such messages but they are seldom used and, depending on your specific case, you could/couldn't reliability depend on such facility.

The use of Multicast translates to lots of savings from a sender point of view: only one send operation needs to occur instead of n*send.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better off to do udp unicast to each host unless you have those very expensive switches. Yes, broadcast/multicast can actually be slower for most switches that have much wimpier CPU than your pcs. Doing anything other than simple forwarding would slow them down tremendously.

Do a benchmark to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Asynch socket programming is definitely the way to go! :)